# array function / error / need for speculation

Tags: c

When I implement my code, my function does not work. However, I don't know the reason why. Can you tell me some problems and how to solve it?

Here's my code! And I'm using language C!
[image: 1]

Comment: Please don't post code as images, instead insert the code into a code block so it can be easily copied and tested.

Comment: As for this specific issue, if you want to pass the whole array, just write the name of the array, don't index it with `[]`. So `findmin(n, arr[n])` -> `findmin(n, arr)`

Comment: okay from next time, I would do so. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function in wrong way:
try this:
findMin(n,arr);
findMax(n,arr);

Whenever you are calling function: in function just pass the array name;

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are calling a array in function just write its array name without [] bracket.

Comment: thank you Mishra I didn't know that. Now I can do it!